# jQuery ui tabs using ajax and fancybox

Tags: fancybox, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page with several tabs where fancybox is used in them, all works well until you select the second tab, then the fancybox stops working.

Main page :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WebShop</title>      

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/igepa.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                $('.ui-tabs-hide').empty();  
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                });
            },
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="test.htm">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.htm">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

test.htm :

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />    

        <script src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/jqgridOpenSource/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/jqgridOpenSource/js/i18n/grid.locale-nl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/jqgridOpenSource/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>           

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                $(".fancybox").fancybox();              
            });             
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.igepa.be/img/items/01-0000-0002Big.jpg"><img src="http://www.igepa.be/img/items/01-0000-0002.jpg" /></a>
</body>
```

Example : http://www.igepa.be/phdj/tabs/tab.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a JS error when switching tabs. On test.html the reference to jquery is not working,change:

```
http://www.igepa.be/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js
```

With the correct jquery url like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

So your browser don't load a new jquery file and use the already cached version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution if I move all the css and js links to the "top" level it works fine.

This is the working code :

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>WebShop</title>      

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/igepa.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />    

        <script src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/jqgridOpenSource/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/jqgridOpenSource/js/i18n/grid.locale-nl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/jqgridOpenSource/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>                

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.igepa.be/includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>           

    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                $('.ui-tabs-hide').empty();  
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                });
            },
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="test.htm">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.htm">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

test.htm :

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                $(".fancybox").fancybox();              
            });             
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://www.igepa.be/img/items/01-0000-0002Big.jpg"><img src="http://www.igepa.be/img/items/01-0000-0002.jpg" /></a>
</body>
```